# Who named the books of the bible?

Tags: bible

We were reading the bible this morning and I asked my mum who named the books of the bible. She wasn't able to answer. Can you?

Comment: The 'books' were actually scrolls. When a scroll got too big they started a second scroll. Hence, 1 Kings & 2 Kings, 1 Chronicles & 2 Chronicles.

Comment: http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/455/how-do-the-books-in-the-bible-get-their-names